# MySQL - updating all records to match max value in group

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table like so

```
id , name , code  ,  flag 
1 ,  john , 1234-3,   2
2 ,  joe  , 1111-2,   1
3 ,  paul , 1234-3,   3
4 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   3
5 ,  asdf , 1111-2,   5
6 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
7,   asdf , 1234-3,   0
```

Basically, what I want to do is set all numbers in the 'flag' feild to the max value related to a specific code.

So in in the case of code 1234-3 it should update all flags with that code with flag num 8
in the case of 1111-2, it needs to update all flags with that code with 5.

I want to transform it into this table

```
id , name , code  ,  flag 
1 ,  john , 1234-3,   8
2 ,  joe  , 1111-2,   5
3 ,  paul , 1234-3,   8
4 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
5 ,  asdf , 1111-2,   5
6 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
7 ,  asdf , 1234-3,   8
```

I'd like to do this in MySQL purely if possible.  There is a very large set of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE  t_transaction tu
JOIN    (
        SELECT  code, MAX(flag) AS flag
        FROM    t_transaction
        GROUP BY
                code
        ) t
ON      tu.code = t.code
SET     tu.flag = t.flag
```

Comment: hmm, that one doesn't appear to be changing the flags as expected.

Comment: First time in ages i did something like this again, this answer helped me out making a somewhat more complicated query

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished very simply in two queries using mysql variables. I would point out that **Quassnoi has a great answer** that may work better for your application.  But this is useful to keep in mind:

If you are using a transactional storage engine (innodb):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @myvar := MAX(flag) FROM t WHERE code = '...'
UPDATE t SET flag = @myvar WHERE code = '...';
COMMIT;
```

If you are using a non-transactional storage engine (myisam):

```
LOCK TABLES t WRITE;
SELECT @myvar := MAX(flag) FROM t WHERE code = '...'
UPDATE t SET flag = @myvar WHERE code = '...';
UNLOCK TABLES;
```