# MySQL updating all records having max value within group

Tags: mysql

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere and I'm just not seeing it; this is the closest I've found, but it isn't quite what I'm trying to do.

[MySQL - updating all records to match max value in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075140/mysql-updating-all-records-to-match-max-value-in-group)

I have a table on a production web server with about 15,000 rows. There are many records sharing an item_name with another record, but item_meters is (normally, but not always) a unique value for each row. item_id is always unique. Currently every record has a value of "0" in the item_flag column.

I would like to update all records with the largest item_meters value within each item_name group to have an item_flag value of "1".

Here is a simplified version of the table ordered by item_id ASC:

```
----------------------------------------------
                  mytable
----------------------------------------------
item_id | item_name | item_meters | item_flag
--------+-----------+-------------+-----------
001     | aaa       | 224         | 0
002     | aaa       | 359         | 0
003     | aaa       | 456         | 0
004     | bbb       | 489         | 0
005     | bbb       | 327         | 0
006     | bbb       | 215         | 0
007     | ccc       | 208         | 0
008     | ccc       | 756         | 0
009     | ccc       | 756         | 0
--------+-----------+-------------+-----------
```

The desired result would be a table with "1" in the item_flag column for each "aaa" having the largest item_meters, each "bbb" having the largest item_meters, each "ccc" having the largest item_meters, etc. like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
                  mytable
----------------------------------------------
item_id | item_name | item_meters | item_flag
--------+-----------+-------------+-----------
001     | aaa       | 224         | 0
002     | aaa       | 359         | 0
003     | aaa       | 456         | 1
004     | bbb       | 489         | 1
005     | bbb       | 327         | 0
006     | bbb       | 215         | 0
007     | ccc       | 208         | 0
008     | ccc       | 756         | 1
009     | ccc       | 756         | 0
--------+-----------+-------------+-----------
```

(In case there are 2 or more records having the same item_name *and* the same item_meters (e.g. item_id 008 and 009 above), the desired result would be for the record with the numerically lower item_id (item_id is always unique), to have an item_flag value of "1" while the row with a numerically higher item_id would still have an item_flag value of "0")

Also of note, even though this database is running behind a production web server with new rows added every day, there will be no need to update the table every time a new row is added. It is something that will only be required once, regardless of whether new rows are later added outside of the parameters. The reason I mention this, is because execution speed is not a big concern since the query will only be executed once.

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if I can provide more info or clarify my question in any way.

Comment: Make a clear expected output here.

Comment: Have you came up with your `query`? can you show us your code?

Comment: Hello @reds, thank you for taking the time to reply. I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding. The expected result would be the second table example given, which shows the desired rows with item_flag = "1"

Comment: Thank you @Luzan Baral, I have thus far only managed queries to select, not update the desired rows. Everything else I have tried has been throwing darts

Comment: You mean all item_flag = 1 is that you need to be an output? The desired result would be a table with "1" in the item_flag

Comment: The flag is redundant (and possibly counter productive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I take is to first write a query (SELECT statement) that will return the `item_id` values of the rows we want to update.

As a starting point, get the maximum value for `item_meters`, a simple query like this:

```
  SELECT m.item_name
       , MAX(m.item_meters) AS max_item_meters
    FROM my_table m
   GROUP BY m.item_name
```

We can use that query as an inline view in another query, to get the lowest `item_id` for each of those `item_name`

```
  SELECT MIN(o.item_id) AS min_item_id
    FROM ( SELECT m.item_name
                , MAX(m.item_meters) AS max_item_meters
            FROM my_table m
           GROUP BY m.item_name
         ) n
    JOIN my_table o
      ON o.item_name = n.item_name
     AND o.item_meters = n.max_item_meters
   GROUP BY o.item_name, o.item_meters
```

And we can use that query as an inline view that gets the whole row associated with the `item_id` values we returned...

```
  SELECT t.item_id
       , t.item_name
       , t.item_meters
       , t.item_flag
    FROM my_table t
    JOIN ( SELECT p.min_item_id
             FROM ( SELECT MIN(o.item_id) AS min_item_id
                      FROM ( SELECT m.item_name
                                  , MAX(m.item_meters) AS max_item_meters
                               FROM my_table m
                              GROUP BY m.item_name
                           ) n
                      JOIN my_table o
                        ON o.item_name = n.item_name
                       AND o.item_meters = n.max_item_meters
                     GROUP BY o.item_name, o.item_meters
                  ) p
         ) q
      ON q.min_item_id = t.item_id
```

Once the SELECT query is working, convert that to an UPDATE statement... replace the SELECT ... FROM with UPDATE, and add a SET clause.  (Sometimes, it's necessary to wrap the inline view in yet another SELECT, to avoid MySQL error about disallowing references to the table we are updating.)

```
  UPDATE my_table t
    JOIN ( SELECT p.min_item_id
             FROM ( SELECT MIN(o.item_id) AS min_item_id
                      FROM ( SELECT m.item_name
                                  , MAX(m.item_meters) AS max_item_meters
                               FROM my_table m
                              GROUP BY m.item_name
                           ) n
                      JOIN my_table o
                        ON o.item_name = n.item_name
                       AND o.item_meters = n.max_item_meters
                     GROUP BY o.item_name, o.item_meters
                  ) p
         ) q
      ON q.min_item_id = t.item_id
     SET t.item_flag = '1'
```

---

If the intent is not to UPDATE the existing table, but to return a resultset, we can write a query and do an outer join to that same inline view, and return either a 0 or a 1 for `item_flag`, testing whether the `item_id` matches one we want flagged as 1...

```
  SELECT t.item_id
       , t.item_name
       , t.item_meters
       , IF(q.min_item_id IS NULL,0,1) AS `item_flag`
    FROM my_table t
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT p.min_item_id
             FROM ( SELECT MIN(o.item_id) AS min_item_id
                      FROM ( SELECT m.item_name
                                  , MAX(m.item_meters) AS max_item_meters
                               FROM my_table m
                              GROUP BY m.item_name
                           ) n
                      JOIN my_table o
                        ON o.item_name = n.item_name
                       AND o.item_meters = n.max_item_meters
                     GROUP BY o.item_name, o.item_meters
                  ) p
         ) q
      ON q.min_item_id = t.item_id
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. I will try this and report back!

Comment: I'm getting this error from the 3rd select query: Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'o.max_item_meters' in 'on clause'

Comment: that should be **`=n.max_item_meters`**, and on the line above that, should be **`=n.item_name`**.  my bad.

Comment: Aha Brilliant! It now works exactly as expected. Thank you very much!